# Convert Swagger Java Object into JSON/YAML

Tags: java, json, yaml, swagger

I need to read, modify and re-generate a JSON/YAML swagger file documentation. I have deserialized a JSON file with Swagger Parser and I have a Swagger Java Object with the original JSON data mapped correctly.

Now, I need to modify the Swagger Java object, and generate a JSON or YAML file with the done modifications.

Is there a way to do that?

Summary:

```
File fileJSON = FileUtils.toFile(getClass().getResource("example-api-rest.json"));

Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read(fileJSON.getPath()); //Got it!
...
swagger.editWhatever
...
//Here I need to generate the JSON or YAML again
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To generate JSON:

```
import io.swagger.util.Json;

String jsonOutput = Json.pretty(swagger);
```

To generate YAML:

```
import io.swagger.util.Yaml;

String yamlOutput = Yaml.pretty().writeValueAsString(swagger);
```

The `io.swagger.util` package is part of [Swagger Core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core), which is one of the dependencies of Swagger Parser.

Comment: What if I don't want it pretty. Is there a way to do this without parsing the string to Java and then back to Json?

Comment: @TheClassic can you please clarify what you're trying to do in the first place? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @TheClassic If you are asking whether the `io.swagger.util.Json` class has a non-pretty output method - this class uses Jackson ObjectMapper internally (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`). So instead of using `io.swagger.util.Json`, you can create and use your own Jackson ObjectMapper instance with the desired serialization settings.