# Spring: How to store 3rd party object in database

Tags: jackson, openapi, jackson-databind

I´m trying to store a third party library object (OpenApi from Swagger Parser) to a database using Spring/Hibernate.
The object implements allot of other objects (representing a whole OpenApi definition).

The object doesn´t implement Serializable so that doesn´t work.
I´ve also tried MessagePack, but there is also the issue, that there is no Template for that. Write the Object to a Json string and store that string did work, but read it from the DB and parse it back to the actual object fails, because there are empty attributes, which are not marked to be possibly empty.

Thank´s alot for any help.

Comment: "...read it from the DB and parse it back to the actual object fails". Why would that fail? I am trying to understand. Why not parse data and save it as jsonb and parse it back from db?

Comment: I´m facing this error when trying to parse the data to the object: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: additionalProperties must be either a Boolean or a Schema instance

Comment: Well atleast post the whole exception you're getting

Comment: Before plus:

 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 33069] (through reference chain: io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI["paths"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Paths["/store/inventory"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem["get"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation["responses"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponses["200"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponse["content"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Content["application/json"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.MediaType["schema"]->io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema["additionalProperties"]

Comment: You can serialize this object to JSON/YAML - see [Convert Swagger Java Object into JSON/YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42978619/113116)

Comment: I think in some way that´s working out quite fine. Thank´s alot